# Is setUbiquitous the only way to move a file to iCloud?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, icloud

The documentation says that `NSFileManager`'s `setUbiquitous` method is the way to move a file to the cloud.  However, I am using `NSFileManager`'s `copyItemAtURL` with an `NSFileCoordinator` to copy a file from the application sandbox to the ubiquity container.  It is working fine.

Is there a problem with this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setUbiquitous is a method, that does `moveItemAtURL:toURL:` with `NSFileCoordinator`, so there is no problems to work with MobileDocuments in a general way using `NSFileManager`

Comment: it actually does copyItemAtURL:toURL: , it does not move the file